# multiple get requests one controller: Unexpected request, unit testing - AngularJS

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I can find plenty of examples of single http calls from a controller and how to test them,but no examples of multiple testing.

My first test works fine without `Product.find(10)` in the controller. When I add that line however the first test collapses.

The errors:

`Error: Unexpected request: GET 0.0.0.0:3000/api/products
    No more request expected`

and

`Error: Unexpected request: GET 0.0.0.0:3000/api/products
    No more request expected`

I've tried a number of things: including both in the before each, this gave me an undefined error, i tried using expect instead of when, I tried adding both whens to both tests, and a combination of the above. I'm clearly doing something very wrong but being an angular newbie, it's hard to work out exactly what that might be, especially with the lack of examples.. I am just looking to get my first test to pass with `Product.find(10)`

Here are my tests:

```
'use strict';

describe('productsController', function() {

    var scope, $httpBackend;
    var api_root = '0.0.0.0:3000/api/';

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sprangularApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject( function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {

        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        //Get mock jsons
        jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/js/tests/api_mock';

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('productsController', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    //Start Tests
    it('Should be array of all products', function() {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products').respond(
            getJSONFixture('products.json')
        );

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.products[3].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Bag');
    });

    it('Should instantiate a new product object from json data', function() {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products/10').respond(
            getJSONFixture('10.json')
        );

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.currentProduct.name).toBe('Spree Ringer T-Shirt');
    });
});
```

my controller that I am testing:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var sprangularControllers;

  sprangularControllers = angular.module('sprangularControllers', ['sprangularServices']);

  sprangularControllers.controller('productsController', [
    '$scope', 'Product', function($scope, Product) {
      Product.products_with_meta().$promise.then(function(response) {
        return $scope.products = response.products;
      });
      return Product.find(10);
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

And the factory with the resource requests:

```
sprangularServices = angular.module('sprangularServices', ['ngResource'])

sprangularServices.factory('Defaults', -> 
    api_url: "0.0.0.0:3000/api/"
)

sprangularServices.factory('Product', ($resource, Defaults) -> 
    # $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products.json')
    class Product
        constructor: ->
            @service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products/:id', {id: '@id'})

        this.products_with_meta = ->
            service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products')
            service.get()

        this.find = (id) -> 
            service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products/:id', {id: id})
            service.get()
)
```

As per michael's suggestion I have edited my test to this, however I am still getting the exact same result:

'use strict';

```
describe('productsController', function() {

    var $rootScope, $httpBackend, createController;
    var api_root = '0.0.0.0:3000/api/';

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sprangularApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        //Get mock jsons
        jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/js/tests/api_mock';

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        createController = function() {
            return $controller('productsController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
        };
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    //Start Tests
    it('Should be array of all products', function() {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products').respond(
            getJSONFixture('products.json')
        );

        var controller = createController();

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($rootScope.products[3].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Bag');
    });

    it('Should instantiate a new product object from json data', function() {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products/10').respond(
            getJSONFixture('10.json')
        );

        var controller = createController();

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($rootScope.currentProduct.name).toBe('Spree Ringer T-Shirt');
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what the controller does, please clarify what you want the controller to do.

Answer (score 2):

Structuring my test in this way seemed to solve the issue:

```
'use strict';

describe('productsController', function() {

    var $rootScope, $httpBackend, createController;
    var api_root = '0.0.0.0:3000/api/';

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sprangularApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        //Get mock jsons
        jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/js/tests/api_mock';

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        createController = function() {
            return $controller('productsController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
        };

        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products').respond(
            getJSONFixture('products.json')
        );

        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products/10').respond(
            getJSONFixture('10.json')
        );

        var controller = createController();

        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        $httpBackend.resetExpectations();
    });

    //Start Tests
    it('Should be array of all products', function() {
        expect($rootScope.products[3].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Bag');
    });

    it('Should instantiate a new product object from json data', function() {
        expect($rootScope.currentProduct.name).toBe('Spree Ringer T-Shirt');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the order of *define the response*, do the *http call*, *flush* and do the *test* is not right.

1. define how the http call should respond

   ```
   $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products').respond(
           getJSONFixture('products.json')
   );
   ```
2. do the call from your code

   ```
   $controller('productsController', {$scope: scope});
   ```
3. flush the httpBackend (e.g. simulate the asynchronous behavior of $http)

   ```
   $httpBackend.flush();
   ```
4. do the test

   ```
   expect(scope.products[3].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Bag');
   ```

because your controller did a backend call in his constructor and is instantiated before you define what the response should be, you got the error.

Further information and an exmaple the is very close to your use case: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried this, but I still have the same problem..please see my edit (i have added the updated test).